# Get elements eq() index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have unknown number of div elements inside parent element. When I click on **child** div element I want to print out its `eq()` index using `console.log()`.
I don't want to use any classes or ids.

HTML:

```
 <div id="parent">
    <div></div><!--if I click on this element eq() should be 0-->
    <div></div>
    <div></div><!--if I click on this element eq() should be 2-->
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(this).click(
    function(){
        console.log(eqIndex);//now this div eq is a problem
    }
);
```

CSS:

```
#parent div{
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:2px;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ccybgmn8/5/)

Comment: It's *well worth* your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It literally takes an hour, two at the most, and it pays you back that time almost immediately.

Comment: `eq()` *in what context* is the question here. index() only returns the `eq()` with regard to **all elements** *in the immediate parent*. You need to make the question clearer.

Comment: Here I edited the question and the code to make it little bit more specific. I want to print out `eq()` index of only child elements of the parent `div`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to bind event with `element selector` and print the result by invoking `.index()` over this object,

```
$('div').click(
    function(){
        console.log($(this).index());
    }
);
```

```js
$('div').click(
  function() {
    $("<p>").html($(this).index()).appendTo(document.body);
  }
);
```

```css
div {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div><!--if I click on this element eq() should be 2-->
<div></div>
<div></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `eq()` *in what context* is the question here. `index()` only returns the `eq()` with regard to **all elements** *in the immediate parent*.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Indeed, very important point. And in fact, in the live example I added, if you put the `script` at the beginning, it has an impact on the indexes (as you know, just flagging it for the OP).

Answer (score 3):

`eq()` *in what context* is the question here. `index()` only returns the `eq()` with regard to **all** elements in the parent. That includes script tags, or any other element type!

In your example you probably want to scope the matches to just the item and its sibling divs, then use that set of divs to determine the index of the one clicked:

```
$("div").on("click", function(){
    console.log( $(this).parent().children("div").index(this) );
});
```

This will avoid the common problem of including too many elements in the collection you index.

e.g.

```
<p>Some other sibling</p>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div><!--if I click on this element eq() do you want 2 or 3? -->
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

If you only want the literal `eq()` value, regardless of other elements, just use `index()` with no parameter:

```
$("div").on("click", function(){
    console.log( $(this).index() );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to grab the index of the clicked div with respect to all divs in the document no matter where they are, you need to use a variant of the [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element) function:

> If `.index()` is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element
>   or jQuery object is passed in, `.index()` returns an integer
>   indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original
>   collection.

```js
$(function() {
  $("div").on("click", function() {
    var index = $("div").index(this);
    /*
     * $(this).index("div") produces same result
     */
    $("#result").text("div:eq(" + index + ") was clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div>0. (1.1)</div>
  <div>1. (1.2)</div>
  <div>2. (1.3)</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div>3. (2.1)</div>
  <div>4. (2.2)</div>
  <div>5. (2.3)</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div>6. (3.1)</div>
  <div>7. (3.2)</div>
  <div>8. (3.3)</div>
</section>
<p id="result">(click the div)</p>
```